# how do I, from chrome extension, open tab wait for user input and go back to extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, callback, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and I have a script that opens a new tab for the user to do something. How can I can get a response from it, but only after the user clicks a button on that new tab, for instance?

Any ideas?

I use chrome.tabs.create to open a new tab, but I guess the callback wont work the way I want it to, right?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to archive, but maybe you should have a look on popups. Would that work too?

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look on popups. What I'm trying to do is the following: my extension shows a bunch of info to the user if they are logged in somewhere. If they're not logged in, they must go to the website and login. What I want is that when they do some actions to try to get the info from my extension but the extenstion tells them to log in, as soon as they do, the extension automatically display the info without the need for the user to do that action again. I hope that made it more clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a content script that'll work only on the desired webpage (where your users log in).
Once you identify the login has been completed (by the page's URL, or by some DOM elements), you can send a message back from the content script to the extension's background process (using [sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html)), and have it do any further necessary action.